# How can I get the hours for now in a time property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli, vuejs3

How can I get now hours, for time property messagesList in VueCLI? When i clicked button, this property is filled as time now. time property will be decimal part. Example : (23.14)

Data is there :

```
 messagesList : [
            {
              id : 1,
              content : "Benim mesajım",
              opposite : false,
              me : true,  
              time : 23.13,   
            },
             {
              id : 2,
              content : "Karşı tarafın mesajı",
              opposite : true,
              me : false,  
              time : 23.13,   
            }
          ],
```

Code is there :

```
this.messagesList.push(
    {
        id : this.messagesList.length + 1,
        content : this.inputText,
        opposite : false,
        me : true,
        time : ?,
    }
```

Comment: What is this time format? Is it hours in the integer part, and minutes in the decimal part?

Comment: It'll be decimal part. Example : 23.14

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, would this do what you want? _(don't use it as it is, it's ugly, I just want to see if that's what you want)_ `time:  (d => parseFloat(d.getHours() + '.' + ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2)))(new Date)` **Note:** if it is, then you might want to change the format, it's very unconventionnal, and not very convenient (how do you know if the message is from last week or from today?)

Comment: I'm new at this platform. Sorry. I have one array for messagesList. messagesList have a property by time. time property should take the current hour and minute. Where can I defined this current time* And how i fill time property this current time?

Comment: This app not connect this database. Only get variable from array for show...

Comment: You can get the current time by creating a `Date` instance: `const time = new Date()`. See [`Date` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you just want to get a current "time" stamp of the current date/time in that format. If so, you can use this ```parseFloat(`${new Date().getHours()}.${new Date().getMinutes()}`)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a function to return the current time in the format you want and call it when adding in the message.

Here is the function:

```
function getTime() {
    return parseFloat(`${new Date().getHours()}.${new Date().getMinutes()}`)
}
```

Here is the push to messageList:

```
this.messagesList.push({
    id: this.messagesList.length + 1,
    content: this.inputText,
    opposite: false,
    me: true,
    time : getTime(),
}
```